# Google BigQuery DML - Slow performance when executing updates & deletes

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-perftools

I have running few BigQuery DML tests to get a better idea of the performance of BigQuery DML capabilities. So far, here are some initial observations:
1) Slow performance when updating only a few records in a very small table (30K+ records)

```
UPDATE babynames.names_2014
SET name = 'Emma B' 
WHERE name = 'Emma';
```

Output: 
- 2 rows affected (# of records in the table:  33176)
- Query complete (4.5s elapsed, 621 KB processed)

---

2) Very slow performance when deleting only few records from a small table

SQL:

```
DELETE from babynames.names_2014_copy
where gender<>'U'
```

Output:
-2 rows affected.
-Query complete (162.6s elapsed, 1.21 MB processed) - ~3 minutes

**QUESTIONS:**
1) Are these known behavior? 
2) Any suggestions on how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is approximately expected - primary DML scenarios are large updates/deletes affecting many rows (millions/billions rows). So latency is less important than throughput.

(2) doesn't look normal - could you try one more time? Anything unusual about table you are trying to update?

> Any suggestions on how to improve the performance?

Optimize towards having few DML statements with each statement updating many rows. For example you may use joins/semijoins to specify large sets of affected rows.

Comment: 1. What do you mean with " latency is less important than throughput"? 2. I've tried few times and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that `Update` and `Delete` operations might me very slow in BigQuery.

Interestingly, overwriting the table with "create or replace table" statement usually has significantly better performance.

So instead of:

```
DELETE from babynames.names_2014_copy
where gender<>'U'
```

consider just using:

```
create or replace table babynames.names_2014_copy
AS
select *
from babynames.names_2014_copy
where not  gender<>'U'
```

A similar technique also works for `Update`; you just need to write a `case` statement to modify your values.

Answer (score 0):

"Interestingly, overwriting the table with "create or replace table" statement usually has significantly better performance." - I'm wondering how much data processing quota is being using with this method :/

My suspicion is - google is trying to limit and slow down these operations on purpose, since big query is strictly non-production database to store data for analytical purposes. I also found that in the morning, when I start some operation it works just fine for a while, then it throttles down. This really makes me think, maybe postgreSQL is a way to go, since bigquery suppose to be easier and more straight-forward, but apparently it's not always a case.